# Import schema.sql into a specificic H2 database with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, h2

I'm struggling to understand if I can import the data defined inside my schema.sql and data.sql into a specific H2 database.

I use Spring Boot 2.0.6 and this is the configuration inside my application.properties:

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:assignment
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

And I correctly placed both schema.sql and data.sql inside the resources folder.

[image: resources]

The application starts up correctly and imports the files:

```
2018-10-26 20:39:24.834  INFO 9448 --- [main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/C:/Users/Gabriele/code/java/assignment/target/classes/schema.sql]
2018-10-26 20:39:24.848  INFO 9448 --- [main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/C:/Users/Gabriele/code/java/assignment/target/classes/schema.sql] in 13 ms.
2018-10-26 20:39:24.850  INFO 9448 --- [main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/C:/Users/Gabriele/code/java/assignment/target/classes/data.sql]
2018-10-26 20:39:24.868  INFO 9448 --- [main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/C:/Users/Gabriele/code/java/assignment/target/classes/data.sql] in 18 ms.
```

But when I open the browser console, the assignment database is empty

[image: assigment database]

while the test one is not.

[image: test]

What am I missing?

Comment: The urls are different: the URL in your screenshot is a file-based H2 database, while the URL in your properties is a memory-based H2 database; they are not the same database.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel, that's right;  
my first attempt was without any configuration so that the database was _test_.

But then, when I switched to the assignment database, specifying it into the configuration, there was no observable effect, like the configuration wasn't applied at all.

Comment: Then please update your question with the actual problem. As it stands the problem seems to be that you are looking at the wrong database:  `jdbc:h2:~/assignment` vs `jdbc:h2:mem:assignment`. The in-memory databases are only accessible to the process that created them.